# Touchscreen doesn't work after installing CarPi

Tags: pi-2, touchscreen

I have a small 5" touchscreen and, with some driver updates and some other things, it *did* work on Raspbian Wheezy.

I installed CarPC over it as required, however my touchscreen stopped working but does display the image. Is there anyone who has an idea how I can solve it? Because it seems I can't boot into Raspbian itself to check the settings. Also running the touchscreen calibration add-on doesn't work and gives the following message:

> Reverse the USB cable from the touchscreen to the RPI.

The thing is that I can't reverse it since it of course only fits one way and also it did work so it can't be the problem.

All help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [these](https://github.com/derekhe/wavesahre-7inch-touchscreen-driver) generic touchscreen drivers. They seem to work with everything (except Kivy)

Comment: thank you for the reply, I will test it as soon as i have time for it.